# Laravel scope not responding

Tags: api, laravel-5

I am using laravel for my backend api.
My question is about an scopefilter, the problem is that it is not responding when I call to it.

I have a lot of examples for using scopefilters.
So I looked at each of them to see if I did something wrong.
But I can't seem to find the problem.

When I call to this model in laravel, I use a parameter to define too the scopefilter to use a specific function.
The point only is that it never gets to this function, I don't get a response when I have put a log in this function.

I assume it is a syntax problem but maybe someone else can find the problem for this.

```
    public static $scopeFilters = [
        "supplierArticleClientId" => "bySupplierArticleClientId"
    ];

    public function scopeBySupplierArticleClientId($query, $clientId) {
        \Log::info([$clientId]);
    }
```

In this case I expect that I see an `clientId` in my log.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a Custom validation function Implementing `Rule` Class
please go through this [link](https://laraveldaily.com/how-to-create-custom-validation-rules-laravel/) for reference